# React JS call function within another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousetrap

I'm trying to call one function from another component in React with the [Mousetrap](https://craig.is/killing/mice) library.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

    } 
    ...
    render() {
      return(...);
    }
}
class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { show: false };
      this.open = this.open.bind(this);
      this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }
    open() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }
    close() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
    }
    render() {
      return(...);
    }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is call `Mousetrap.bind('e', function(e) { Child.open() });` somewhere in the parent (because the parent will be rendered, and the child will only be rendered on this command).  But, I'm not sure where to actually include that.  Would it be better to call that in the constructor, or somewhere in `render()`, or somewhere else I haven't considered?

Comment: Mind if I ask why? From what you've shown, you could instead have `show` be passed into `Child`'s props, then instead of the parent calling `open`, the parent would re-render itself with a new value of `show` passed to the child.

Comment: That makes sense. But then where would I include the Mousetrap code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to have that be part of your state, e.g.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this._eKeyPress = this._eKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.state.showChild = false;
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    Mousetrap.bind('e', this._eKeyPress);
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    Mousetrap.unbind('e', this._eKeyPress);
  }
  _eKeyPress(){
    this.setState({showChild: true});
  }

  render(){
    return <Child show={this.state.showChild} />;
  }
}
```

The next question after that is whether you need to create the child at all, since you could also do

```
render(){
  return this.state.showChild ? <Child /> : null;
}
```