# How to call function/method of another class in setState of GET/POST react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a GET and POST for my customer class and now I want to close the AddCustomer form and refresh the table in Customer class.

I want to call  closeCreateForm of AddCustomer in Customer class.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class AddCustomer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showCreateForm:false,
        formData:{
            name: '',
            address: ''
        }
    }
    this.handleChangeName = this.handleChangeName.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeAddress = this.handleChangeAddress.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChangeName(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;

    console.log(value);

    this.setState({formData:{name:value, address:this.state.formData.address}});

    //name: ""
    //address: ""
    console.log(this.state.formData);
}

handleChangeAddress(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    this.setState({formData:{name:this.state.formData.name, address:value}});

    //name: "ram" but now there is no address in formData
    console.log(this.state.formData);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    ////address: "aaaaa" now there no name in formData
    console.log(this.state.formData);

    this.setState({formData:{
        name:this.state.name, address:this.state.address
    }});
    this.props.onAddFormSubmit(this.state.formData);
}

//On cancel button click close Create user form
closeCreateForm = () => {
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: false })
}

//Open Create new Customer form
openCreateCustomer = () => {
    this.setState({ showCreateForm: true })
}

render() {

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal closeOnTriggerMouseLeave={false} trigger={
                <Button color='blue' onClick={this.openCreateCustomer}>
                    New Customer
        </Button>
            } open={this.state.showCreateForm}>
                <Modal.Header>
                    Create customer
    </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Content>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                        <Form.Field>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder ='Name' name = "name"
                                value = {this.state.name} 
                                onChange = {this.handleChangeName}/>
                        </Form.Field>

                        <Form.Field>
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input type="text" placeholder ='Address' name = "address"
                                value = {this.state.address}
                                onChange = {this.handleChangeAddress}/>
                        </Form.Field>
                        <br/>
                        <Button type='submit' floated='right' color='green'>Create</Button>
                        <Button floated='right' onClick={this.closeCreateForm} color='black'>Cancel</Button>
                        <br/>
                    </Form>

                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```

In her customer class onAddFormSubmit get called and new record is submitted to database then I want to clothe this form and refresh the table tor new data.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AddCustomer from './AddCustomer';

export default class Customer extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onAddFormSubmit = this.onAddFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        isLoaded: false,
        formClose:false,
        users: []
    }
}

//fetch data 
componentDidMount() {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    myHeader.append('Origin','https://localhost:44387');

    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        myHeader
    };

    fetch(customerApi, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            this.setState({
                users: result,
                isLoaded: true
            });
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setState({
                isLoaded: true,
                error
            });
        }
    )


}

//close form
closeForm = event => {
    this.props.closeCreateForm();
}

async onAddFormSubmit(data) {

    const customerApi = 'https://localhost:44387/api/Customers';

    const myHeader = new Headers({
        'Accept':'application/json',
            'Content-type':'application/json'
    });

    fetch(customerApi,{
        method:'post',
        headers:myHeader,
        body:JSON.stringify(data)

    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        (result) => {
            console.log("Customer add result");
            console.log(result);
            this.setState({

            })
        },(error) => {
            this.setState({ error });
        }
    )
}

onEditCustomer = customerId => {
    console.log("Clicked"+customerId);
}

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
            <AddCustomer onAddFormSubmit = {this.onAddFormSubmit}/>
            <Table celled textAlign='center'>
                <Table.Header>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>ID</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Address</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                        <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Header>

                <Table.Body >
                    {
                        users.map(user => (
                            <Table.Row key={user.customerId}>

                                <Table.Cell>{user.customerId}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.name}</Table.Cell>
                                <Table.Cell>{user.address}</Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='blue' onClick = {()=>this.onEditCustomer(user.customerId)}>Edit</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <Button color='red'>Delete</Button>
                                </Table.Cell>

                            </Table.Row>
                        ))
                    }
                </Table.Body>

                <Table.Footer>
                    <Table.Row>
                        <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='5'>
                            No of Pages
                    </Table.HeaderCell>
                    </Table.Row>
                </Table.Footer>
            </Table>

        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React JS call function within another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442606/react-js-call-function-within-another-component)

Comment: You shouldn't do that, react is declarative, not imperative. You should consider using a store (look at context API if you don't want to use a library).